# Elastic Beanstalk Instance logs not being streamed to Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have log streaming ticket in my ELB Configuration page but in my Cloudwatch Logs i can only see eb-activity, httpd and nginx log groups. I am expecting to see the Tail and Bundle instance logs from the individual EC2 nodes. Isn't that the expected behaviour of ELB?

Do i need to do anything additional to get my instance logs to appear to CW?

Answer (score 3):

The awslogs agent looks in the configuration file for the log files which it's supposed to send. There are some defaults in it. You need to edit it and specify

You can check and edit the configuration file located at:

```
/etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf
```

Make sure to restart the service:

```
sudo service awslogs restart
```

You can specify your own files there and create different groups and what not.

Resources:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html

Comment: Thanks. Interesting that the logs being captured by default in ELB is not streamed to CloudWatch. Basically the only logs being streamed by default is elb-activity, httpd and nginx. Not ideal

Comment: @Max if it helped you, please accept the answer as the right answer :)